# Searching for obesity data at the ZIP or County level by age for US 2011-1013?

Tags: data.gov

Searching for obesity data at the ZIP or County level by age for US 2011-1013

Comment: It'd be nice if you could actually phrase this as a question, so it looks like you've spent a little bit of effort here.

Answer (score 2):

The [BRFSS](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/) identifies respondents in most U.S. counties. However, the coverage is not exhaustive. But there exists small area estimations that usually use BRFSS data as the reference.